# How to handle a function with multiple sequential inputs for ipywidgets

Tags: python, ipywidgets

So I am writing an `ipywidgets` with 20 alpha values and these alpha values are controlled by their own slider.
I need to assign each alpha value to a matrix.

The idea is shown in the following codes:

```
# Initialize the sliders
for x in range(20):
    globals()['alpha_slider%s' % x] = FloatSlider(min=-0.01, max=0.01, step=0.001)

def interactive_vis(pitch, yaw, roll, x, y, z,alpha0,alpha1...alpha19):
  for i in range(20):
      alpha_matrix[i][0] = alphas{i}
```

I tried to store all the sliders in a list and feed it to the function.

1. It appears that the `alphas` to the function is not a list as how I `[]` them.

```
from ipywidgets import interactive, interact, Layout
from ipywidgets import FloatSlider
from ipywidgets import IntSlider
from ipywidgets import HBox, VBox, Label

def interactive_vis(pitch, yaw, roll, x, y, z,alphas):
  for i in range(20):
      alpha_matrix[i][0] = alphas[i]
widget = interactive(interactive_vis, 
            pitch=pitch_slider, yaw=yaw_slider, roll=roll_slider, x=x_slider, y=y_slider, z=z_slider,
            alphas=[alpha_slider0,alpha_slider1,alpha_slider2,alpha_slider3,alpha_slider4...alpha_slider19])

TypeError: 'FloatSlider' object is not subscriptable.
```